# How to use ServiceStack Session cross Domain?

Tags: servicestack

I'm ServiceStack newbie. Thank your good job. I encountered a problem about Session.
There are two projects, a ServiceHost, another is ASP.NET MVC 3 website.
ServiceHost used for Request Dto, Response Dto & Service Defination. for used ServiceStack Session, I register a new session feature plugin and cacheclient to IOC. all these at Service Host Project.
How can I use the ServiceStack session at MVC project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheriting from the [ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs) base class provides access to ServiceStack's [typed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs#L63) and [un-typed sessions bag](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs#L78).

The ServiceStackController is available in the [ServiceStack.Mvc](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Mvc) and [ServiceStack.Host.Mvc](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc) NuGet packages.

More info about ServiceStack's sessions is contained in the [Session wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions).

Comment: thanks for your answer, the apphost defined in service layer(one machine), and session & cache registerd in it. the web site in another machine, could be share singlton session between them?

Comment: You can't share singletons across different machines? If using 2 different processes you need to use a distributed cache like Redis or Memcached. In same AppDomain you can use MemoryCacheClient.